# updatemany by taking existing field value and and new field in moongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

this is my schema

```js
const winSchema = new mongoose.Schema( {
    windo_no:Number,

  
    time:{
        start_time:  {hours: {
            type: Number, min: 0, max: 23
          },
         minutes: {
            type: Number,  min: 0, max: 59
          }
         },

        current_time:  {hours: {
            type: Number,  min: 0, max: 23
        },
        minutes: {
            type: Number,  min: 0, max: 59
        }},
        
        end_time:  {hours: {
            type: Number,  min: 0, max: 23
        },
        minutes: {
            type: Number,  min: 0, max: 59
        }},
   
    },

    date:[{
        date:String ,
        holiday:Boolean,
        allocation:[{
            tokenid:Number,
            compelte:{
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            },
            m_number:Number,
            services_id:Number,
            allocated_time:{hours: {
                type: Number,  min: 0, max: 23
            },
            minutes: {
                type: Number, min: 0, max: 59
            }},

        }]
    




    }]

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Window', winSchema)
```

I will run query every day in which I want to update for all windows current_time will be equal to  start_time  at single time
trying to do updatemany() but how to get and  set value from already inserted field value

```
 // set current_time=starttime
 router.post("/settime", async (req, res) => {


  let result = await model.updateMany({ },
   {
   $push: {time:{ current_time: {hours:11}} },
  },
```

)});
here I despite of writing hours:11 I want to add start_time hours field value

```
 let result2 =   await model.updateMany({},{
 $push: 
   // {'time.current_time': 'time.start_time'}
     {time:{ current_time: "$start_time"} },
   })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 let result2 =   await model.updateMany({},
 [{$set:{"time.current_time":"$time.start_time"}}])
```